# 2nd law of thermodynamics for non-quasistatic processes

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

The 2n law of thermodynamics can be stated in terms of entropy as follows

> $dS \geq \frac{dQ}{T},$

which holds for all quasistatic processes (reversible and irreversible ones).

Is there a generalization of this statement to a general process between two equilibrium states $e_1$ and $e_2$ (a non-quasistatic process)? I.e. can one write down a similar inequality for $\Delta S = S(e_2) - S(e_1)$ (linking it to $\Delta Q$ and so on)? Or at the very least, is it possible to derive the well-known $\Delta S \geq 0$ for an isolated system?

I'm aware of the fact that one can always write $\Delta S = \int_{\gamma} \frac{dQ}{T}$ for any reversible process $\gamma$ driving the system from to $e_1$ to $e_2$. However, it's not obvious how to exploit this, if at all.

Comment: Where are you getting the inequality from  in the entropy definition?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. The fact that it's an inequality rather than an equality?

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant. The definition of entropy is $$dS=\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}$$

Comment: Yes, but the inequality holds for all quasistatic processes, in particular for irreversible ones for which it is a true inequality

Comment: Ok you acknowledge that is not the definition of entropy correct? Do you know what an irreversible quasistatic process is?

Comment: You want me to give you an example?

Comment: Yes please. I know what it is. I would like to post an answer for you but would like know at what level you are first.

Comment: From wikipedia "An example of a quasi-static process that is not reversible is a compression against a system with a piston subject to friction."

Comment: Ok so one last question. Why are you limiting the inequality to only quasistatic irreversible processes. Why not all irreversible processes?

Comment: The differential statement dS doesn't make sense for non-quasistatic processes. Also T (as well as S) is only defined during equilibrium, so there is no way to parametrize T for non-quasistatic processes

Comment: Your last comment is incorrect.  The T in the Clausius inequality must be taken as the temperature at the interface between the system and its surroundings (where the heat transfer dQ is occurring), and is not the temperature of the system.  This temperature is readily accessible to measurement and to specification.  And the Clausius inequality must be more precisely specified as $$\Delta S\geq\int{\frac{dQ}{T_I}}$$where $T_I$ is the temperature at the interface.  So there is no ambiguity with regard to $\Delta S$.

Comment: @user2224350 Chet Miller is correct. The inequality applies to any irreversible process. See the following https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node48.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Clausius inequality holds not only for quasi static process but for all processes carried out on a closed system.  That is, it holds if it is expressed correctly:  $$\Delta S\geq\int{\frac{dQ}{T_I}}$$ where $T_I$ represents the temperature at the interface between the system and its surroundings (where the heat transfer dQ occurs).  The integral in the equation represents physically the entropy transferred into the system from the surroundings.  The reason that $\Delta S$ is greater than this for an irreversible process is that, in addition to the entropy transferred in from the surroundings, entropy is also generated within the system.  Such entropy generation does not occur in a system experiencing a reversible process.

Comment: Can you provide any source or derivation for this?

Comment: Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics, Moran, et al, Section 6.7.    Thermodynamics, Enrico Fremi